# How to directly use raw Ajax on IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-7

We have a webpage that uses WebService.htc to call a web service. This is a very old page and we are having some relability problem with it.

Without using any of the available framework out there. Is there a new (hopefully more robust) way to access a web service in IE 7?

Answer (score 0):

you can make a webservice call directly using javascript.. however. it cannot be as robust as a java or .net client (not to say that clients using other technologies are not robust)..

you can find a very helpful article on [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/callWebServiceUsingJS.aspx) on calling web services using java script.

Comment: He is using webservice.htc. I was wondering if there were'nt any build-in javascript function in todays browser (IE7) to do the same thing (calling a web service).

Comment: no IE7 is not bundled with functionality to call a web service. There are only workarounds